# Run remote app but not the entire desktop

Tags: java

In the company where I work we have, among others, an application made in Java running on two places (let's say Merida and Coatza) and both have different databases. The users from Merida only occasionally used the program to get some info or capture things. Now the company owner decided to control almost everything from Merida but we cant get the databases merged due to operation logistic.

The thing is that when the application uses the persistence-unit to connect coatza it's incredibly slow since the app its not prepared to use remote databases (at least not with a high performance).

I thought of something like teamviewer to run the app remotely but not the database, however I don't want to run the complete desktop, only the application. Or develop a part of the program on JCurses so it can be run from coatza but there is not enough documentation and we use a lot of tablemodels.

Is there something I could do?

The application is a DesktopApp. We use Jboss 5 as server. Hibernate and JPA.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone could help you on this as its pretty broad. I mean is database access slow because of latency, or poor coding? If poor coding, why not fix it?

Comment: You need to provide more info like if the Desktop app is only a facade and contains no logic. Meanwhile if you are in a hurry try some commercial solution like citrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar situation where we needed to use the same application at different locations because the license was too expensive. I used a feature called RemoteApp on Windows Server 2008. The best part is that you can have a desktop shortcut for any app on a remote computer and all you need to do is open it and login and only that particular app starts running instead of the whole desktop. There is also a web interface for remoteapp so that you can simply login and select whichever app you want to run. For more details take a look at http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Configuring_RemoteApps_on_Windows_Server_2008

Comment: Thank you Vinit. I'll be evaluating both, citrix and RemoteApps on windows. I hope to be posting soon about it so anyone with the same requirement can know too.